# Laravel: how order by many to many table?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have tables

```
users
    id
    username

role
    id
    name

users_role
    user_id
    role_id
```

I have users listing and I want ability to sort by username and role_id, how I can do this?

```
users
1:first
2:second
3:third

roles
1:admin
2:customer

users_role
1:1
1:2
2:2
3:2
```

Sort can be by first user role_id(or for max role_id -> if user have roles 1 and 2 sort by 2)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to create relationships for two model: User and Role (i suppose that we have three tables: **users**, **roles** and **role_user**:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function roles() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Role');
    }
}

class Role extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\User');
    }
}
```

Next, with this query you can have list of users and roles, sort by username ASC and role_id DESC

```
\App\User::with(array('roles' => function($query) {
                            $query->orderBy('role_id', 'DESC');
                        }))
                        ->orderBy('username', 'ASC')
                        ->get();
```